# Skew image over one vertical side

Tags: android, matrix, graphics, transformation, skew

I am trying to "skew" an image on the left side, by 10%. This way it looks as if it is turned a bit. I thought the easiest way of doiing this is create a custom "skewedimageview" which extends ImageView and with an overriden setFrame method.
So to be a bit more clear: this is what I want
[image: skewed image on left side vertical]

But although I tried a lot of possible matrix combinations, and tried setting  [setSkew](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#setSkew(float,%20float,%20float,%20float)) (it sounds like this is what I want). I tried with and without defining the pivot point, but both did not work. I was also not sure what point to choose as pivot point: it should be a point that stays unchanged, but I think during this transformation there are a lot of unchanged points (full right side and horizontal centerline).

What I also tried was [mapPoints](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#mapPoints(float[])) and then just lower the top-left corner with 5% and the bottom right corner up with 5% but that also did not seem to work.

```
     @Override
    protected boolean setFrame(int frameLeft, int frameTop, int frameRight, int frameBottom) {


        Matrix matrix = getImageMatrix();

        matrix.setSkew(1f,0.9f);

        setImageMatrix(matrix);
        return super.setFrame(frameLeft, frameTop, frameRight, frameBottom);
    }

}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this and what the best practice is, using setSkew or mapPoints ? Or create a transformationmatrix manually (but I think that must be much harder than using these methods).

**Edit:**
As suggested by [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) I used the function setpoly2poly as follows:

```
 @Override
    protected boolean setFrame(int frameLeft, int frameTop, int frameRight, int frameBottom) {
        float height = frameBottom - frameTop;
        float width = frameRight - frameLeft;
        System.out.println("Height is "+height);
        int dy=0.05*height;

        Matrix matrix = getImageMatrix();
        float[] startpoints = {0,0,0,height}; //{0,0} =top left, {0,height}= left bottom
        float[] endpoints = {0,0+dy,0,height-dy}; //topleft 5% down, bottom left 5% up
          matrix.setPolyToPoly(startpoints,0,endpoints,0,2);
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
        return super.setFrame(frameLeft, frameTop, frameRight, frameBottom);
    }
```

It does something, but the main thing it does is zooming in to the left top of the image...

Comment: Matrix.setPolyToPoly()

Comment: btw you don't need custom ImageView: just set scaleType to "matrix" and setup the matrix using setPolyToPoly()

Comment: Thank you, I tried the setpoly2poly function, see edit in post... I am using an imageview to simply reuse this transformation. By changing ImageView to the custom view in XML, I automatically have the skewed image I want, easy since I use it in multiple places.

Comment: use more points,  2 is definitely not sufficient

Answer (score 1):

I was faced with this problem and find a solution ~!

```
Bitmap bitmap = addWhiteBorder(bitmapsrc, 2);
Matrix matrix2 = new   Matrix();
int oldw = bitmap.getWidth();
int oldh =  bitmap.getHeight(); 
float d_up = oldh / 20; 
float d_down = d_up + 10;
float[] src2 = new float[] { 0, 0, oldw, 0, oldw,
                                oldh, 0, oldh };
float[] dst2 = new float[] { 0, d_up, oldw, 0,
                                oldw, oldh, 0, oldh - d_down };
matrix2.setPolyToPoly(src2, 0, dst2, 0,
                                src2.length >> 1);
Bitmap bMatrix2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
                                bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),
                                matrix2, true);                         
imBookCover.setImageBitmap(bMatrix2);
```